# How Can I Point My Local Testing Server at My GitHub Repository?

Tags: git, github

Up until a few days ago, I had a particular setup that was as follows. Using SVN, all of the websites that I developed were committed to a source control drop box on a local testing server. Then using IIS, a new website was set up to point at the last revision of each particular website I developed and display it to the outside world using a specific URL.

I have just moved over to using git and github, meaning all of my source controlled code is now no longer stored on a local testing server. As a result of this, I am not sure how I can go about doing a similar thing to what I did with the SVN setup, however I need to be able to essentially have that same setup again, just using Git.

So basically, how can I go about getting my local testing server to point at the GitHub repository for that site?

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you saying that your using your testing server both as a repository and as a production server for your sites? from reading your question they appear to be the same box

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't really understand your question. Do you want to checkout all the github repos to your local test server where the IIS is running and test the code there?

So basically you might want to clone the github repo to there as a local instance.

To do that:

```
git config --global github.user user_name
git config --global github.token asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd
git clone git@github.com:user_name/project.git
```